# Transforming data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

What would be the best way to approach this problem using python and pandas?

I have an excel file of electricity usage.  It comes in an awkward structure and I want to transform it so that I can compare it to weather data based on date and time.

The structure look like ( *foo is a string and xx is a number*)

```
100,foo,foo,foo,foo

200,foo,foo,foo,foo,foo,0000,kWh,15

300,20181101,xx,xx,xx,xx...(96 columns)xx,A

... several hundred more 300 type rows
```

the 100 and 200 rows identify the meter and provide a partial schema.  ie data is in kWh and 15 minute intervals.  The 300 rows contain date and 96 (ie 96 = 24hours*4 15min blocks) columns of 15min power consumption and one column with a data quality flag.

I have previously processed all the data in other tools but I'm trying to learn how to do it in Python (jupyter notebook to be precise) and tap into the far more advanced analysis, modeling and visualisation tools available.

I think the thing to do is transform the data into a series of datetime and power.  From there I can aggregate filter and compare however I like.

I am at a loss even to know what question to ask or resource to look up to tackle this problem.  I could just import the 300 rows as is and loop through the rows and columns to create a new series in the right structure - easy enough to do.  However, I strongly suspect there is an inbuilt method for doing this sort of thing and I would greatly appreciate any advise on what might be the best strategies. Possibly I don't need to transform the data at all.

Comment: For many good pandas data questions, 3 essential components are included: 1) attempted code, 2) **actual** data (placeholders are difficult to understand), and 3) desired output. Please include all three.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data easy enough into a `DataFrame`, you just have to step over the metadata rows, e.g.:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<file>, skiprows=[0,1], index_col=1, parse_dates=True, header=None)
```

This will read in the csv, skip over the first 2 lines, make the date column the index and try and parse it to a date type.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I had pretty much got this far but you have provided significant improvements on my import code.  It is indexing the 96 15min power data columns on time that I am struggling with.

Comment: Show the code that you have and what you are looking to do (in the question), then you will likely get more help.